# Gather Information About Image File

Tags: php, html, image, image-processing

I want to gather information about an image, such :- 
Camera used, Focal Length, Shutter Speed, Aperture, ISO, Date taken on, Dimensions and other details.
I am developing in PHP. I am unable to find any Function for such thing. Is there any possibility to do this in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information can be found in the EXIF from a shot (if that is provided!).
You can find yourself a library now with that word, but I suggest you start here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php

Comment: thankss nanne. Lets start it. Any problem , i will post. Jingles |||